How to query for an amount when it changes values base on a record
I am trying to query for an amount when it changes base on a record. For example the below table.
I want to query for the rows with a (****). I want to know whenever the balance changes for each acct. Once i have that i want to show the difference from the latest balance to the previous balance change... so for acct 123456 i want to query for when balance change from 1000 to 2000 and show the difference in another query does not need to be all in one query. Hope i am making sense any help is appreciated.



ACCT
BALANCE
TIME




123450
1000.00
2008-01-30 00:00:00.000 ****


123456
1000.00
2008-02-29 00:00:00.000


123456
1000.00
2008-03-31 00:00:00.000


123456
1000.00
2008-04-30 00:00:00.000


123456
1000.00
2008-05-31 00:00:00.000


123456
2000.00
2008-06-30 00:00:00.000 ****


654321
1000.00
2008-02-29 00:00:00.000


654321
2000.00
2008-03-31 00:00:00.000 ****



Desire query results



ACCT
BALANCE
TIME




123450
1000.00
2008-01-30 00:00:00.000 ****


123456
2000.00
2008-06-30 00:00:00.000 ****


654321
2000.00
2008-03-31 00:00:00.000 ****



i have found the query below but it does not work for what am looking for.
DECLARE @x TABLE(acct INT,  balance money,[time] DATETIME)

INSERT @x VALUES
(123450,'1000.00','2008-01-30 00:00:00'),
(123456,'1000.00','2008-02-29 00:00:00'),
(123456,'1000.00','2008-03-31 00:00:00'),
(123456,'1000.00','2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
(123456,'1000.00','2008-05-31 00:00:00'),
(123456,'2000.00','2008-06-30 00:00:00'),
(654321,'1000.00','2008-02-29 00:00:00'),
(654321,'2000.00','2008-03-31 00:00:00');
select * from @x
; with temp as
(
SELECT 
    acct, balance, [time],  lag(balance) over (order by [time] ) as lastValue
FROM    @x
) 
SELECT 
    acct,[time] , balance
FROM 
    temp 
WHERE acct > lastValue
order by acct, time 


Please do take a moment to take note of the preview of the question before you post it. The preview is there for a reason (your question is lacking any markdown); don't rely on other users to improve your post to make it readable.

In addition to the comment by @Larnu above, your question seems to not include the expected output.

I see no changes to accnt # 123450. Why it is marked as a desired output?

sorry guys i was able to format and add desire query results

@serg there are going to be times an act does not have any changes... it may just have one single line of record.

You are comparing your account number with the balance, which is not what you want.  Compare the balance with the last balance:
 WITH temp AS (
     SELECT 
         acct, 
         balance, 
         [time],  
         LAG(balance) OVER (ORDER BY [time]) AS lastValue
     FROM @x
 )
  SELECT 
     acct,
     [time],
     balance
     balance - lastValue as change
 FROM temp
 WHERE balance <> lastValue
 ORDER BY acct, [time];


Thanks guys for all of the help. I am picking up a previous balance (lastvalue) of a different account. How can i force the query to give me 0 if the previous act does not match or if the balance never changes.
